# Filtering the Eventlog entries using c#

Tags: c#

I am using EventLog class for querying event log entries in local computer. But I am unable to determine a way to apply a filter here. I want to query only error event type which has a specific event ID. Is it possible with this class? or I should be using different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use EventLogEntryType in the EventLogEntry class to compare the event type.

```
EventLogEntry evntEntry; //Fill it using your own code like loading from event log list

if(evntEntry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error)
{
  //
}
```

You can also add event id check in the similar way, using the 'EventID' property

Comment: How to do filter them by event ID?

Comment: It is a late reply but still doing because it may be useful to someone else. The `EventLogEntry` class also has `EventID` property. You can check like `if (evntEntry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error && evntEntry.EventID == 'xxxx')
                {
                   //
                }`

Comment: Might be worth noting the EventLogEntry.EventID property is marked obsolete by Microsoft. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396